# Run new conversation in current

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I use that PHP Telegram SDK: https://github.com/akalongman/php-telegram-bot

How I can run a new Conversation in current Conversation? I have a KeyboardButtons and when user clicks on "Feedback" button, bot starts the new dialog (conversation) like "write your message for admins". I have a StartCommand with code:

```
<?php
namespace Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\SystemCommands;

use Longman\TelegramBot\Conversation;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Commands\SystemCommand;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\InlineKeyboard;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\InlineKeyboardButton;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\Keyboard;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\KeyboardButton;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Entities\Chat;
use Longman\TelegramBot\Request;

class StartCommand extends SystemCommand
{
    protected $name = 'start';
    protected $description = 'Start command';
    protected $usage = '/start';
    protected $version = '1.1.0';

    public function execute()
    {
        $message = $this->getMessage();
        $chat = $message->getChat();
        $user = $message->getFrom();
        $text = trim($message->getText(true));
        $chat_id = $chat->getId();
        $user_id = $user->getId();

        $data = [
            'chat_id' => $chat_id,
        ];

        if ($chat->isGroupChat() || $chat->isSuperGroup()) {
            $data['reply_markup'] = Keyboard::forceReply(['selective' => true]);
        }

        // Conversation start
        $this->conversation = new Conversation($user_id, $chat_id, $this->getName());
        $notes = &$this->conversation->notes;
        !is_array($notes) && $notes = [];
        // cache data from the tracking session if any
        $state = 0;
        if (isset($notes['state'])) {
            $state = $notes['state'];
        }
        $result = Request::emptyResponse();

        switch ($state) {
            case 0:
                $keyboards = [];
                $keyboards[] = new Keyboard(
                        ['Information'],
                        ['Books', 'Feedback'],
                        ['Hide menu']
                    );

                $keyboard = $keyboards[0]
                        ->setResizeKeyboard(true)
                        ->setOneTimeKeyboard(false)
                        ->setSelective(false);

                if ($text === '') {
                    $notes['state'] = 0;
                    $this->conversation->update();
                    $data['text']         = 'Please choose a section:';

                    $data['reply_markup'] = $keyboard;
                    $result = Request::sendMessage($data);
                }
                elseif ($text === 'Information') {
                    $this->conversation->update();
                    $data['text'] = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../other/texts/infrormation.txt');
                    $data['reply_markup'] = $keyboard;
                    $result = Request::sendMessage($data);
                }
                elseif ($text === 'Books') {
                    $this->conversation->update();
                    $data['text'] = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../../other/texts/books.txt');
                    $data['reply_markup'] = $keyboard;
                    $result = Request::sendMessage($data);
                }
                elseif ($text === 'Feedback') {
                    /**
                     * HERE NEED START NEW CONSERVATION
                     * LIKE THESE (StartCommand or SurveyCommand)
                     */
                }
                elseif ($text === 'Hide menu') {
                    $this->conversation->stop();
                    $data['text'] = 'Done!';
                    $data['reply_markup'] = Keyboard::remove();
                    $result = Request::sendMessage($data);
                }
                $notes['name'] = $text;
                $text          = '';
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many solutions is in creating dedicated group for this conversation. For redirecting to this group just use invite link (you can get it from group description) and provide it in bot's message if **ReplyKeyboardMarkup** used or **url** field of button for **InlineKeyboardMarkup** (preferred in my opinion).

Also you can use [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage). When user hit the **Feedback** button let your bot send *"write your message for admins"* as you said and let it be with [ForceReply](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forcereply) option. After this you need to check your received messages for **reply_to_message** field is not null. If so - then get this message for forwarding to admins group (or channel).